# Weaker Than The Weak Topology?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, uniform-spaces

The weak topology on a Banach Space $E$ is defined to have sub-base consisting of open balls of the form $B_\alpha(x,r) = \lbrace y \in E : \vert \alpha(x-y) \vert < r\rbrace $ for each $x \in E$ and $r > 0$ and $\alpha \in E^*$ . This defines a uniform structure which is also a topological group.

Is there any reason we would want to define a similar topology, but only using a proper subset of the seminorms induced by dual space elements? That is the topology on $E$ with sub-base consisting of balls of the form $B_\beta(x,r) = \lbrace y \in E : \vert \beta(x-y)\vert < r\rbrace $ for each $x \in E$ and $r > 0$ and $\beta \in H \subset E^*$. Here $H$ is a proper subset of $E$. I think we can exclude the case where $E = F^*$ and $H = F$.

Looking at a silly example where $H$ contains only one element that returns 1 on a given Hamel basis element $e_0$, and 0 on all other elements, gives a topology containing only $E$, $E -$ span{$e_0$}, span{$e_0$}, and $\varnothing$. Clearly vector space operations are not continuous in this topology. Nevertheless it is still a uniform space. But do uniform spaces of this form come up anywhere?

Comment: The topology induced by a single $\lambda \in E^\ast$ is not what you describe. It is always a (locally convex) vector space topology, usually not a Hausdorff topology, though (it is Hausdorff if and only if $\dim E = 1$ and $\lambda \neq 0$). That is rarely interesting. A topology induced by a separating family of linear functionals however is more often interesting.

Answer (score 1):

What you might be looking for is this: If $E$ is a real or complex vector space, $E^*$ its *algebraic* dual and $H \subseteq E^*$ a sub vector space and you endow $E$ with the weak topology induced by $H$, then $H$ becomes the topological dual of $E$. (The polars in $E^*$ of the $0$-neighbourhoods in $E$ are the weak-$^*$-closure of the absolutely convex hulls of finitely many points in $H$, which are just the absolutly convex hulls of finitely many points. The union of all these sets is the topological dual of $E$ which is therefore $H$.)

Applying this to your question: If you choose $H$ as a non-trivial true sub vector space of the topological dual of a Banach space (you can always do this as the comment under the question explains), then the resulting space has a different (smaller) topological dual than the space you started with. If you want this to happen, then you define such a "even weaker topology" (most of the time you don't ;-)).